# Type Error $.widget is not function

Tags: jquery

I am using two [jquery](/questions/tagged/jquery) plugins one is for Auto complete combo box and another for i Toggle button.Problem is that when I am accessing these two plugins at a time  $ widget is not function error is displaying,but if I am giving these plugins individually no errors are displaying.Can you guys help me on this?

Comment: do you have jquery ui added to the page

Comment: yes this is for combobox                                           <link rel="stylesheet" href="../../../jquery/jquery-ui.css" />
    <script src="../../../jquery/jquery-1.8.2.js"></script>
    <script src="../../../jquery/jquery-ui.js"></script>                                                             this is for i Toggle button                     <!---// load the iButton CSS stylesheet //---> 
<link href="../js/jquery.ibutton.css" rel="stylesheet" /
<script  src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.3.2/jquery.min.js"></script> 
<script  src="../js/jquery.ibutton.js"></script>

Comment: what is the jquery ui version and whether the file location is valid

Comment: but i copied the files for combo box into my root folder

Comment: check your browser developer tool's network tab to see whether all the dependency files are available

Answer (score 3):

You are including jQuery twice. This is the problem. Just avoid the second including:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="../../../jquery/jquery-ui.css" />
<script src="../../../jquery/jquery-1.8.2.js"></script>
<script src="../../../jquery/jquery-ui.js"></script>

<link href="../js/jquery.ibutton.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="../js/jquery.ibutton.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 1):

Try adding the latest versions of jQuery & jQuery UI.

http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js

http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.2/jquery-ui.js

Latest versions of jQuery will support latest version of jQuery UI, hence try taking the latest version of both jQuery and JQuery UI.

Answer (score 1):

Problem was in order of including scripts. At first I included file fith my widget and jquery-ui after. I changed order and the problem was resolved.

Comment: Same here.  Easy mistake to make.  Just ensure you properly load the UI package before a dependent library.